# Solve the differential equation $(x+5)y'+5y=\frac{3\sin x}{(x+5)^4}, x>-5$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What does it mean to solve the differential equation?  For example,

Solve the differential equation 
$$
(x+5)y'+5y=\frac{3\sin x}{(x+5)^4}, x>-5
$$

I believe I am to put this in the form of $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$. Then integrate using $$v(x)=e^{\int Pxdx}$$.

If this is the technique I am to use when solving these problems, I seem to be having trouble identifying what is $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'(x)(5+x)+5y(x)=\frac{3\sin(x)}{(5+x)^4}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Divide both sides by $5+x$:

---

$$y'(x)+\frac{5y(x)}{5+x}=\frac{3\sin(x)}{(5+x)^5}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $v(x)=\exp\left[\int\frac{5}{5+x}\space\text{d}x\right]=(5+x)^5$

Multiply both sides by $v(x)$:

---

$$y'(x)(5+x)^5+5y(x)(5+x)^4=3\sin(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Set $5(5+x)^4=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left((5+x)^5\right)$:

---

$$y'(x)(5+x)^5+y(x)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left((5+x)^5\right)=3\sin(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)(5+x)^5\right)=3\sin(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)(5+x)^5\right)\space\text{d}x=\int3\sin(x)\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)(5+x)^5=\int3\sin(x)\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\frac{\int3\sin(x)\space\text{d}x}{(5+x)^5}=\frac{\text{C}-3\cos(x)}{(5+x)^5}$$

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!!!